# How to delete blank rows in spss modeler

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

I have four columns, three are integers and one is nominal. The nominal columns has blank values(null) and the other three columns have no blanks.

I want to select only the rows where the nominal column is not blank and the corresponding values for the other three columns.

I have tried @NULL, @BLANK on the nominal column but the output has blanks included. I get a message that string + integer cannot be merged for condition.

Please advise how do i do it. I am using SPSS Modeler 18.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the fields x1,x2,x3 (integers) and y1 (string), your data looks like

1 2 3 'blue'

2 2 1 'green'

1 1 1 ''

And you only want to remove the last row? You tried

**select**(**remove**): if @NULL(y1)

I would do

**select**(**remove**): if y1=""

Comment: Let me try that. Thank you.